# How can I compare liquid concentration to solid concentration?

Tags: concentration

Total novice here!
I'm trying to determine which is more sensitive between two drug tests, 1 that uses ng/ml and the other that uses pg/mg.  Is there a way to standardize concentrations to compare liquids to solids?

For example determining concentrations of THC: cut-off in liquid is $\pu{50 ng/ml}$ and in solid is $\pu{1pg/mg}$.  I want to know which is a more sensitive test.  Is it just as simple as knowing a picogram is smaller than a nanogram?

Comment: What are NG, MG, PG, ML and THC?

Comment: In order: nanograms, miligrams, picograms, mililiters and Tetrahydrocannabinol (the high inducing component in marijuana)

Comment: You need to mind the capitalization. Nanograms = ng, miligrams = mg, picograms = pg, mililiters = mL.

Comment: @andselisk Correction: millilitres = ml. Only in some education systems and journals is the SI convention not followed and nonstandard mL used for millilitres.

Comment: @Jan To my knowledge it's exactly the opposite. ACS Style Guide suggests using "L" exclusively, BIPM allows both, but "L" is again preferred over "l" "*in order to avoid the risk of confusion between the letter l (el) and the numeral 1 (one)*". In IUPAC color books it's also primarily "L", and vendors also use "L" (at least what I saw in Germany and Russia). The only institution I know really like "l" is ISO, but who cares about them:)

Comment: @andselisk ‘The litre, and the symbol lower-case l, were adopted by the CIPM in 1879 (PV, 1879, 41). The alternative symbol, capital L, was adopted by the 16th CGPM (1979, Resolution 6; CR, 101 and Metrologia, 1980, 16, 56-57) in order to avoid the risk of confusion between the letter l (el) and the numeral 1 (one).’ [Source](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf), directly from the BIPM. Lowercase l is the standard symbol according to BIPM, uppercase is an alternative. This alternative is only really popular in the US, Canada and Australia afaik.

Comment: @Jan I have no idea what's going on – this is the same citation I provided, but expanded, and it doesn't reinforce your point whatsoever. BIMP allows both, but the latter amendment in my understanding have higher priority and overall brings up a good point: from the typographical point of view "L" is overall better. Unless there is a solid evidence that "l" must be preferred, I'd say it's just unnecessary nitpicking.

Comment: @andselisk There is absolutely nothing from a typographical point of view that makes the uppercase intrinsically better, and it was explicitly added as an *alternative* not as the standard. Since the BIPM sets the SI standard, their word is the standard and the alternative is not the standard. Also, you never gave a source.

Comment: @Jan Your statements about typography contradicts your cited text from BIMP (which I provided a link to with a quoted text – the source is easily googleable, so I thought it shouldn't be a problem for you to follow up) – "l" is very ambiguously font-dependent (good luck distinguishing "l", "I", "|" written with Arial), whereas "L" is clear and font-agnostic. There is a major typographic improvement. BIMP **equally** allows both "L" and "l".  ChemSE uses ACS style for drawing structures, but you for some reason decide to dodge their recommendations when it comes to units. I don't follow you.

Comment: @andselisk Well, the symbol for litres hardly ever appears isolated. I have yet to come across an actual *use* of the symbol where ambiguity may arise. I for my part cannot make sense out of a milli-one and no unit exists abbreviated I to the best of my knowledge. The style question is easy: I conform to the highest standard where it makes sense and to an arbitrary one where none exist. I repeat that alternative is not equal.

Comment: @Jan I don't know the amounts you are dealing with, but I again vastly disagree. Lab solvents are shipped in liters; I synthesize precursors in liter amounts, and good portion of people I deal with use "L" just as often as "mL". To the BIMP part – what makes you think "l" has the priority? They are both listed as equal notations (in text and in Table 6), but as "L" has been suggested later in a form of amendment, it has somewhat higher priority as an improvement of the existing standard (compare with US Constitution and Amendments). And again, what's wrong with ACS standards?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68004/discussion-between-andselisk-and-jan).

Comment: Thanks all, like I said total novice.  I was going off of the promotional materials sent to me from the drug testing company and everything was capitalized.  I appreciate the correction!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the density is ~1, i.e. that of water or dilute solutions, 1 ml weighs about 1 g or 1,000 mg. 1 nanogram, ng, is 10<sup>-9</sup> g and 1 picogram, pg, is 10<sup>-12</sup> g. Therefore:

> 1 ng = 1,000 pg
>
> 1 ml ≈ 1,000 mg

E.G. if the test can detect 1 ng/ml, that would be *approximately* 1,000 pg/ 1,000 mg or 1 pg/ml.

Note that this assumes samples are prepared the same way and are tested in the same concentration. If the sensitivity quoted in pg/mg is for a *dry* sample, the comparison is meaningless.